# A Euler summation like inequality.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, inequality

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} $ be a continuously differentiable function. Let $n$ be an integer. Why do we have:
$$\int_n^{n+1} f(t) dt = f(n)+O\left(\int_n^{n+1} |f’(t)| dt\right)?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\eqalign{\left\vert \int_n^{n+1}f(t)dt-f(n)\right\vert&=\left\vert \int_n^{n+1}(f(t)-f(n))dt\right\vert\cr
&=\left\vert \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^tf’(u)du dt\right\vert\cr
&\le\int_n^{n+1}\int_n^t\vert f’(u)\vert du dt\cr
&\le\int_n^{n+1}\int_n^{n+1}\vert f’(u)\vert du dt\cr
&=\int_n^{n+1}\vert f’(u)\vert du 
}$$
and the desired conclusion follows.